# Complex trigonometry problem

Tags: trigonometry

The value of $$\large \displaystyle e^{\log(\tan 1^\circ) + \log(\tan 2^\circ)+ \cdots+\log(\tan 89^\circ)}$$
Base is $10$. I guess it should simplify to $\large\displaystyle e^{89 \log(\tan 1^\circ)}$. 
Please help.
 I tried attempting the problem.
The options in book are

$A.\ 0$

$B.\ e$

$C.\ \dfrac1e$

$D.\ \text{None of these}$

The answer is none of these. That's why I am confused.

Comment: There is a ......... In place of till.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

Use $\displaystyle\log a+\log b=\log(ab)$ where all the logarithms remain defined

and $$\tan(90^\circ-x)=\cot x=\frac1{\tan x}=(\tan x)^{-1}$$

$$\implies \log[\tan(90^\circ-x)]=?$$

**See also**: [$ \tan 1^\circ \cdot \tan 2^\circ \cdot \tan 3^\circ \cdots \tan 89^\circ$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805704/tan-1-circ-cdot-tan-2-circ-cdot-tan-3-circ-cdots-tan-89-circ?rq=1)

Comment: Ahh I got it. T

Comment: So the answer is 1?

Comment: @user166748, $$e^{\log 1}=e^0=?$$

Comment: Yaa that's what I calculated. Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: @5xum  what do you mean? I know that this exactly what I needed so I accepted it.

Comment: @user166748 No, you just upvoted the question. Accepted by clicking on the tick mark under the voting score.

Comment: that happened by mistake. Sorry