# Trick for converting integral to a sum

Tags: definite-integrals, summation

If $$\text {I}=\int_0^{\infty} \frac {x}{1+e^x} \, dx $$ and $\sum _{i=1}^n \frac {1}{k^2}=\frac {\pi^2}{6} $ 
I am feeling that this integral need not be solved analytically but should be converted into sum so that we can use the next information given. The only step I have taken  is $$\text {I}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int _0^n \frac {x}{1+\sum_{i=0}^n \frac {x^n}{n!}}\, dx$$

Comment: Hint :$ 1/(1+e^{-x})$ can be written as a geometric series

Comment: Be care changing limit and integral.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Here are some approaches that use the sum you mention [How to find $ \int_0^\infty \dfrac x{1+e^x}\ dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798895/how-to-find-int-0-infty-dfrac-x1ex-dx). Also this one looks good [Finding the integral of $\frac{x}{e^x + 1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835886/finding-the-integral-of-fracxex-1?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint for $ x>0$ we have $0\le e^{-x}<1$ then we have

$$\frac {1}{1+e^x} =\frac {    e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n e^{-(n+1)x}$$

From this we have $$I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac {x}{1+e^x} \, dx  =\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n 
\int_0^{\infty}  xe^{-(n+1)x}\, dx$$
From you can easily get the result after integration by part..

Answer (score 3):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x dx }{ e^x-1} &=& \int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x e^{-(i+1)x} dx  \\
&=&  \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-(i+1)x} dx  \\
&=&  \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(i+1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Or
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x dx }{1+ e^x} &=& \int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^ix e^{-(i+1)x} dx  \\
&=&  \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (-1)^i\int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-(i+1)x} dx  \\
&=&  \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^i}{(i+1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{12}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Edit:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{e^x-1} =\frac{1}{e^x} \frac{1}{(1-e^{-x}) } =\sum_{i=0} ^{\infty} e^{-(i+1)x}.
\end{eqnarray*}