# Prove that a definite integral is an infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

I've been trying to solve this given equality involving an improper integral and an infinite sum without any substantial progress:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{1+e^x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}$$

I tried various integration techniques such as change of variable ($1+e^x=t$ ; $e^x=t$), integration by parts and used Taylor expansion at every integral I arrived. However, I did not find any way of expressing the integrand as an infinite sums of functions that I could integrate term by term.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that the sum in question is equal to $\pi^2/12$.  For more information, look up the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find $ \int_0^\infty \dfrac x{1+e^x}\ dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798895/how-to-find-int-0-infty-dfrac-x1ex-dx) (Your result is proved in the intermediate steps in Ron Gordan's answer; it also shows the sum is equal to $\pi^2/12$ as mentioned by Michael Seifert)

Answer (score 13):

It's really just a geometric series:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x\,dx}{1+e^x}&=\int_0^\infty xe^{-x}(1+e^{-x})^{-1}
=\int_0^\infty x\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}e^{-nx}\,dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\int_0^\infty xe^{-nx}\,dx
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: (+1) That was nice!

Comment: How did you make the following step? : $\int_0^\infty xe^{-x}(1+e^{-x})^{-1}
=\int_0^\infty x\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}e^{-nx}\,dx$. Thanks!

Comment: @Matthieu the only reasonable explanation is a power series expansion, because it is $e^{-nx}$ suggests it is in the variable $e^x$ which seems about right to me: that sum could be the power series expansion (in the variable $e^x$) of $e^{-x}(1 + e^{-x})^{-1}$.

Comment: @Cryvate yes, I see this now. Thank you.