# Failure to justify switching common integral

Tags: real-analysis

I wanted to evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{xe^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} \, dx$ and found this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/798903/148510) where it is shown

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{xe^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} \, dx = \int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kxe^{-(k+1)x}\, dx = \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\int_0^\infty xe^{-(k+1)x}\, dx $$

In the last step, switching the sum and integral is justified by answerer *"because the sum and integral converge."* There are many examples where changing the order of a convergent infinite series and convergent infinite integral is not allowed.

How is this justified here?  Monotone convergence does not help.

Comment: Dominated convergence. Take the absolute value of each term, then you still get a convergent sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case we can be brutal, taking the absolute value of each term still leads to a convergent sum and integral because the factor $x$ cancels the pole of $\frac{1}{e^x-1}$ at $0$ if we do so. Thus changing the order is justified by the dominated convergence theorem.

We can be more conservative too, if we wish (and if we considered the integral of $\frac{1}{e^x+1}$ instead of $\frac{x}{e^x+1}$ we would have to be). The series is alternating, with the terms decreasing in absolute value (except at $0$, where all terms have absolute value $1$), thus
$$0 \leqslant \sum_{k = 0}^{N} (-1)^ke^{-(k+1)x} \leqslant e^{-x}$$
on $[0, +\infty)$ for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$, and we can appeal to the dominated convergence theorem with dominating function $xe^{-x}$. This works for
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{f(x)}{e^x+1}\,dx$$
whenever $f(x)e^{-x}$ is Lebesgue-integrable on $[0,+\infty)$. (Whether it helps determining the value of the integral is a different question.)